# not loading js/css file in jade

Tags: angularjs, node.js, pug, cloud9-ide

I am pretty new in **jade**, in my **node.js** project, no js and css external file is being loaded. I am using **jade** as **template engine**, **bower_component**, **angular.js** as javascript mvc, **bootstrap** for css framework and **Cloud9** as editor. My code is given below :

My Project Structure::

```
 -jobproject
 |----node_modules
        |-- bower
        |-- express
        |-- jade

 |---public
        |--- app
              |-- app.js
        |--- bower_components
              |-- angular
                    |-- angular.js
              |-- bootstrap
                    |-- dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
              |-- jquery
 |-bower.json
 |-index.jade
 |-package.json
 |-README.md
 |-server.js
```

In **server.js** file ::

```
 var express = require("express");
 var app = express();

 app.set('views', __dirname);
 app.set('view engine', 'jade');  // jade view engine

 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

 app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.jade');
 });

 app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP); // default cloud9 port
```

In **index.jade** ::

```
 link(rel="stylesheet", href="bower_conponents/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")

 script(type='text/javascript', src='bower_conponents/angular/angular.js')
 script(type='text/javascript', src='/app/app.js')

 body(ng-app='app')
    div(ng-controller='testCtrl')
       div {{ test }}

       span(class='btn btn-primary') hello world
```

In **app.js** ::

```
 angular.module('app', []);

 angular.module('app').controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = 'working';
 })
```

In the browser window :

```
 {{ test }} <!-- should be "working"
 hello world <!-- show be bootstrap button style, but only plain text -->
```

In console window :

```
angular.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks you should try :

```
 link(rel="stylesheet", href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")
 script(type='text/javascript', src='bower_components/angular/angular.js')
```

Instead of :

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="bower_conponents/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")

script(type='text/javascript', src='bower_conponents/angular/angular.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo error maybe. Bower conponents?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using heroku as per the tutorial you are doing, make sure you add your files and commit them and push to heroku before you try to see the changes.